# SUM() subquery for total money spent for each customer

Tags: php, mysql

I'm stuck on a problem and I need help. So, I need to find the total money spent per customer. In the database, one customer_id has multiple payments.
This is my code:

```
"SELECT customer.first_name, customer.last_name, customer.customer_id, address.address, city.city, address.postal_code, SUM(amount) as money_spent
FROM customer, address, city, payment
WHERE customer.address_id = address.address_id
AND address.city_id = city.city_id
GROUP BY customer_id
ORDER BY customer.last_name ASC;");
```

However, that column only repeats the total amount for all customers. How to fix this?

Comment: `FROM customer, address, city, payment` this form of join is deprecated and easily leads to the problem you are seeing.  Explicitly join with JOIN...ON: `FROM customer JOIN address ON customer.address_id = address.address_id JOIN city ON address.city_id = city.city_id JOIN payment ON ...` (note that your where is missing the join condition for payment)

Comment: resulting in every payment being included for every customer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with this query is here:

```
FROM customer, address, city, payment
WHERE customer.address_id = address.address_id
AND address.city_id = city.city_id
```

You're missing the `AND payment.customer_id = customer.id` part for the `payment` table. In this case, the database joins **all** payments for **each** customer. So when you get the result, you're getting the total sum for all payments with each customer.

Note: the `AND payment.customer_id = customer.id` part depends on the database structure. Update `payment.customer_id` and `customer.id` accordingly.

Comment: PS: don't forget to add indexes ;) without them, this query can slow down pretty quickly.